# Wordpress - Plugin name?

Tags: wordpress, adblock, readblock

when **adblock working** show look like picture
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5AYo.png)

and when adblock doesn't work, show advertisement, 
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Something like [Simple Adblock Notice](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-adblock-notice/) ?

Comment: I understand, I'm sorry I got it wrong, but thank you for telling me!